# CellDataFeatures.getValue.get() no longer supported?

Tags: java

The code underneath is from this example: http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/19/dyanmic-tableview-data-from-database/comment-page-1/

But I can't get the param.getValue().get(j)) to work, has it been deprecated? There is no option to use get() on getValue().

```
        for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j));
                }
            });
```

Comment: `Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String>` as I always say, this is a sign for a bad design.

Comment: How about my posted answer, is that bad design ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, for anyone wondering:

You need to add TableColumn in front of the CellDataFeatures.

See updated working example

```
(int i=0 ; i<rsa.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
            //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;                
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rsa.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){                    
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {                                                                                              
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());                        
                }                    
            });

            tableView.getColumns().addAll(col); 
            System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
        }
```