# Param.getValue.get() not working

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I've tried to figure out why I can't use this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)
{
    final int j = i;
    TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
    col.setCellValueFactory(param ->
                    new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString()));
    showTableMembers.getColumns().addAll(col);
}
```

Well, it's close to be working, but

param.getValue().***get(j)***.toString()

is not working. The `get(j)` just gives compilation error.

I've tried: [CellDataFeatures.getValue.get() no longer supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481931/celldatafeatures-getvalue-get-no-longer-supported) . 
Sadly it didn't work.

So now I wonder how to get that working?

Hope anyone in here has the suggestion to solve my small problem :)

Comment: Do you get a more specific error message in the console or by mousing over the red text? Also, I'm not sure if you accidentally removed it while omitting code from the question, but you're missing the closing `);` from your `col.setCellValueFactory`.

Comment: It just says: Cannot resolve method 'get(int)'. Beside that, it has no syntax errors. The closing brackets should be placed right, I believe?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misread your code due to the indentation of the next line. They are correct, yes. What is `param`?

Comment: Param is just the lambda name expression, that I've chosen. I could have called it anything :)

Comment: My bad. I haven't used Lambdas much. :P

Comment: Don't use raw types. Use the correct type for your `TableColumn`, i.e. `TableColumn<S,T>` where `S` is whatever the type of the rows are in your table and `T` is whatever the type of the cells are in the column. (You have basically [asked this before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145135/tableview-javafx-the-type-of-getcolumns-is-eroneous).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the exact type as

```
TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> col = new TableColumn<>(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Could you give a short explanation why it needed to defined in that way? :)

Comment: Java is *strongly typed*. The compiler determines which method calls are allowed by the type of the reference on which you are invoking them. What is the type of `param.getValue()` with raw types (your code) or with the correct types (Uluk's code)?